# Thread Index in PLINQ Query?

Tags: c#, .net, plinq

Is there way to pass the thread "index" of a PLINQ query into one of it's operators, like a Select?

The background is that I have a PLINQ Query that does some deserialization, the deserialization method uses a structure (problably an array) to pass data to another method:

```
      ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, nrObjects)
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(8)
        .Select(i => this.Deserialize(serializer, i, arrays[threadIndex]))
        .ToList();
```

(threadIndex is the new variable I'd like)

If I knew the thread index I could create 8 of these arrays upfront (even if all might not be used) and reuse them. The Deserialization method might be called millions of times so every small optimization counts..

Comment: i can't understand why you can't use `i`? it will be unique across the computations

Comment: @Andrey - if I have the intent correct, he wishes to *safely* re-use a small number of working buffers for the operations.

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ you are right, i reread question carefully

Comment: Yeah, exactly :) and buffer is the wrong word perhaps here, it's just a small array, as I said, micro-optimizing

Answer (score 1):

Re the **thread** index; note that the degree of parallelism is (IIRC) only the **maximum** number of threads to use; it doesn't *have* to use that number. Relying on `threadIndex` in the way you describe would seem to mean that you might *actually* only access `arrays[0]`. So in short, no: I don't think so.

You *can*, however, get the **item** index; so if that is what you mean, simply:

```
.Select((value, itemIndex) => this.Deserialize(
     serializer, i, arrays[itemIndex])).ToList();
```

It *sounds* (comments) like the intent is for obtaining a working buffer; in which case, I would (and indeed, *do*) keep a few convenient buffers in a container (with synchronized access etc), i.e.

- attempt to obtain an existing buffer from a container (synchronized)
- if not found, create a new buffer
- (do work)
- return/add buffer to the container (synchronized)

This will generally be very fast (much faster than buffer-allocation per iteration)

Comment: Yeah I know... but if only one array is reused and used simultaneously that's ok. Just have to avoid the same array being used by different threads

Comment: @MattiasK - I'll take a guess this is a scratch buffer, right?

Comment: Yeah :) I don't want to create an array for each item, that would kinda defeat the purpose.   I'm experimenting with letting the Deserialization method pack each field into an array which is sent to an adapter which sets the object's values. I'm trying to minimize casting so it isn't easy :)

Comment: I can't really use synchronization or other threading mechanisms in this case because it would take more time than just creating the array (we're talking a (2-8 item array so it's at the nanolevel :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) of integers and then take from it before deserealization use as index and then return after. Every thread will occupy one array element at a time.

Consider using [Parallel class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx). It is more appropriate when it comes to arrays. There are limitations on indexed versions of `Select` if you use `ParallelEnumerable` (Not in your case, but be cautious)

Comment: I've tried using Parallel and ConcurrentBag but the performance is far too bad  (I've measured) for this case  when the methods being called takes very little time but is called many many times

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Parallel.ForEach which offers an overload that allows you to allocate (and cleanup) locals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992638.aspx) that will be passed into one parallel instance of the loop at a time. I've used this approach for processing of large sets of image data where I require buffers for various steps of the process.